# How to scrape multiple tables of one page in wikipedia page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape all the tables of the following page into one big table;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes

But the problem is my code only seems to download Pilot table and none of the others. I have looked at the html and noticed that they all have the same class so how do I differentiate between them.

Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
My_table = soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})
print(My_table)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to target all tables, you can just select all tables that match your criteria `select` will return **all** tables:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
print(soup.select("table.wikitable.plainrowheaders.wikiepisodetable")
```

If you want to target each table individually, you can utilize the `:has()` selector to target the header before the table that contains the specific `id` that you would like, followed by the `+` combinator that will find the next child. Here is a simple example targeting two of the tables.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
for tid in ('Pilot', 'Series_A_\\.282003\\.29'):
    table = soup.select_one("h3:has(span#{}) + table.wikitable.plainrowheaders.wikiepisodetable".format(tid))
    print(table)
```

You can extend similar logic to target whatever you'd like.

EDIT: Use `select_one` in the second example as we are targeting a single table opposed to *many* tables.

Comment: I like this. Why doesn't, for example, h3:has(span#Pilot)  select anything if I use it via devtools on the actual page itself? Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You have to enable the experimental flag `Experimental Web Platform features`, in `chrome://flags` (but it can cause issues on some pages so I wouldn't recommend leaving it on). `:has()` is a level 4 selector planned for the [snapshot profile](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#profiles) only. Not many have implemented it, and it is a bit experimental, but for scraping it can be quite useful which is why I implemented it in Soup Sieve (the underlying select library).

Comment: It's also possible that I'm getting selectors confused, and chrome doesn't support it even with the flag enabled: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility. I tested so many during development that I may be mistaken which ones are supported in browsers  :).

Answer (score 2):

Try using find_all instead, note this will return a list of nodes instead of just one node.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find use find_all. find_all returns all the nodes with the corresponding properties whereas find just returns the first node.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
my_tables = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})
for table in my_tables:
    print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas read_html

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes'
re = requests.get(url, headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'})
df = pd.read_html(re.text)
print(df)
```